# What the right variable to use here, that represents the TARGET field in the .pro file

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I would like to add a custom command, that will work on the generated binary file (The target field in *.pro file),

[image]

But what should I use here, in the `Command arguments`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. QtCreator only handles source and build directory. The [QtCreator documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-build-settings.html#using-qt-creator-variables) says:

> The following Qt Creator variables are available:
>
> ```
>     %{buildDir}
>     %{sourceDir}
> ```

Note that the target even doesn't have to be in the build directory. The build directory is where qmake is ran, typically resulting in the target being put there, because in the .pro file one typically specifies `TARGET = projectName`.

Further note that the QtCreator build steps configuration only works *within QtCreator*. This should not be used when your custom build steps are needed for other people working without QtCreator (they should only run qmake and make to build your application).

This being said and assuming that you want to define a *post-build step*, you should look for a solution to define such in the .pro file (by using the `$${TARGET}` variable) so that qmake will put your buildstep into the Makefile after the linking step.

If you want to execute a command after linkage, let's say call a custom script (batch script on Windows, otherwise a bourne shell script) with the TARGET as an argument, add the following to your .pro file:

```
win32 {
    poststep.commands = @myScript.bat $${TARGET}
}
!win32 {
    poststep.commands = @./myScript.sh $${TARGET}
}

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += poststep
```